# Is auto_prepend_file the same as "require"? (fails with register_shutdown_function)

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling, require

The php manual says:
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the
>   main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require
>   function, so include_path is used.

**Let's do a test**

*register_shutdown_function.php*

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
register_shutdown_function('foo');
function foo() {
    if(!is_null($e = error_get_last())) {
        echo 'bar';
    }
}
?>
```

*.htaccess*

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /www/public_html/register_shutdown_function.php
```

*index.php*

```
<?php
echo '
?>
```

Result: "bar" is displayed. Works as expected.

**Next test**

We delete the *.htaccess* and change the *index.php* as follows:

```
<?php
require('register_shutdown_function.php');
echo '
?>
```

Now register_shutdown_function() is not called?!

It works only with this *index.php*:

```
<?php
require('register_shutdown_function.php');
include('file_with_parse_error.php');
?>
```

Is this a bug or something related to PHP 5.4.37 (FastCGI)? I'm asking because sometimes I needed to delete and/or overwrite the .htaccess file multiple times to "enable" or "disable" *auto_prepend_file*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP must parse a file before it will run it.

Since `echo '` is a parse error, your file won't be run at all, which means the require will not happen.

If your error was `echo 1/0;` (not a parse error) then your file would work as expected.

**Edit:** You need to call `register_shutdown_function` before PHP reads the file that has the parse error.  In your first and third example you are doing that.

Comment: In my third test you see that require works. In my first test "bar" is displayed as well. Test it in your own.

Comment: @mgutt Yes because in your third test you do not have a parse error in the file that has the require, so the require happens.

Comment: Ok, but where is the difference between the first and the second test? The manual says "if it was called with the require". I did that.

Comment: The manual says that they will both use the include_path, which is correct, but that is unrelated to your issue.  The difference is that in your first example, PHP has already ran `register_shutdown_function.php` before it even tries to parse `index.php`.  In the second example it tries to parse `index.php` first and fails because it can't.  It doesn't even look at `register_shutdown_function.php` because it has already failed.

Comment: I think maybe the confusion is that the require is before the parse error so it should've ran.  But that is not the case, PHP will parse the entire file first.  By having `auto_prepend_file` in the htaccess file, that file is parsed separately from (and before) the one with the error.

Comment: Yeah, the "included as if it was called with the require" confused me. I'll ignore that. The important sentence is "parsed before the main file".

Comment: Now, I found the reason for my confusion. I first read the german text "Hier können Sie eine Datei angeben, die automatisch vor der Hauptdatei aufgerufen wird. Die Datei wird in die aufgerufene Datei eingebettet, als wenn Sie sie mittels der require Funktion eingebunden hätten, dabei wird ein gesetzter include_path beachtet.". The german word for "to parse" is "parsen" and not "aufgerufen" which means "called". Finally I used the english version for my question at stackoverflow but did not read it carefully again. I will search how to submit translation corrections on php.net.